# How to autowire Quartz JobListener

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Spring annotations to wire my application dependencies.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to inject my JobListener to the Quartz SchedulerFactoryBean as it is configured here:

```
   @Bean(name="schedulerFactory")
   public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
       SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
       schedulerFactoryBean.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
       schedulerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
       schedulerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
       // This call results in the error:
       //   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Non-global JobListeners not supported on  
       //   Quartz 2 - manually register a Matcher against the Quartz ListenerManager instead
       //schedulerFactoryBean.setJobListeners(new JobListener[] { jobActivityListener() });
       return schedulerFactoryBean;
}
```

I am currently having to programmatically configure the JobListener to be created when the job is first triggered:

```
ListenerManager listenerManager = scheduler.getListenerManager();
if (listenerManager.getJobListener(jobKey.getName()) == null) {
    logger.debug("ADDING JOB LISTENER FOR " + jobKey.getName());
    listenerManager.addJobListener(new JobActivityListener(), keyEquals(jobKey));
}
```

This is not ideal, as we would like Spring to manage the dependencies, and inject the dependencies needed by the JobListener.

Is there any information on configuring the job listeners via Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not exactly related to the job listener, but ultimately if you want to inject the listener via the @autowired location, in your xml configura file you have to define simply the mapping (do care about the service/component name ) and that should do the trick..
It' show i inject service in Quartz job actually.